# Which statetment is kotlin-way?

Tags: kotlin, coding-style

In kotlin, you have at least two options for function definition using assignment, like below:

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/")
fun controllerMethod() = service.internalMethod()
```

or

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/")
fun controllerMethod() = service::internalMethod
```

Which option is kotlin-way? I think the second option is more "javaish", but i don't have much expirience in kotlin to decide.

Comment: These two mean totally different things. Did you mean `val controllerMethod = service::internalMethod`? But then `@GetMapping` would have nowhere to go.

Comment: @Sweeper No, i meant `fun controllerMethod() = service::internalMethod`.  I'm not sure if it works, but compiler allows it.

Comment: Yes, the compiler allows it, but it doesn't *mean* the same thing as `fun controllerMethod() = service.internalMethod()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper), I understood the difference.

The function `fun controllerMethod() = service.internalMethod()` returns the result of `internalMethod()` calling, but the function `fun controllerMethod() = service::internalMethod` returns the `kotlin.reflect.KFunction` reference to the method.